# How to make regex to check single quotes?

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

I want to replace only a single quote to double quotes but when I try it using regex it also replaces double quotes with two double quotes.

I used `(['])` as regex but it returns true for double quotes also.

- eg: when I passed ->     don't      : it is working correctly
- but when I passed ->     don''t     : it is not working correctly final output became don''''t

I want to convert only single quotes to double quotes. How can I do this?

Comment: how can we help you if you dont post your code... post the code!!

Comment: Use `(?<!')'(?!')`.

Comment: why would you want to use regex?

Comment: simply I need regex for check only single quote sir, previously I used ([']) as regex but it returns true for double quotes also

Comment: It is very confusing when you say *double quotes* and are talking about a *pair* of single-quotes `'` (aka [apostrophes](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm)), not a *standalone* double-quote `"` (aka [quotation mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm)).

Comment: Why not just use String#replace() which doesn't use a regex. It would be easier and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, by "double quotes", you mean "double single-quotes".

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
(?<!')'(?!')
```

To find a single quote that's not followed or preceded by another single quote (using a negative Lookbehind and a negative Lookahead). Then you simply replace it with `''`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jlCcbi/1)**.

**Java example:**

```java
String s = "don't, don''t";
String output = s.replaceAll("(?<!')'(?!')", "''");
System.out.println(output);   // Prints "dont''t don''t"
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/SZNE47851)**.